# Why should the optimum position of GPS Antenna be close to aircraft's CG?

Tags: gnss, radio-navigation, antenna

In CAE OAA Book11-Radio Navigation Chapter-18 Page-318, under GPS Error, "The optimum position for the antenna is on top of the fuselage close to the aircraft's centre of gravity".

[image: Reference]

In the FCOM of A320, GPS(MMR) Antenna are situated in the front of the fuselage

[image: FCOM-A320]

My questions are:

1. Why are all GPS Antenna situated on top of fuselage ?. (Is it because of satellite reception)
2. Why is the GPS (MMR) antenna situated in the front top of the fuselage ?.
3. Why GPS antenna should be close to aircraft's CG ?.
4. Why are there 2 GPS Antenna ?. (Is it because of redundancy or because faster lock-in?.)

Comment: This is pure speculation, but maybe it's because CG is basically the "centre" of the aircraft; on large aircraft, the extremities might be quite far away from the CG, and placing the antenna there might reduce the accuracy (e.g. if the antenna was placed at the wingtip, the location it would show might not give a good picture of the "average" location of the aircraft).

Comment: @AdityaSharma To avoid speculations, i have attached image from an official book. If it is given, there will be reason behind it.

Comment: Surely there must be a good reason; I was just sharing my thoughts. Good day.

Comment: Not a full answer, but consider that when a long aircraft changes pitch attitude, the nose and tail will move by several meters in opposite directions. Placing the antenna near the CG mitigates perceived altitude changes due to this effect, especially during altitude-sensitive phases of flight, like on an RNP approach.

Comment: Is it not true that an aircraft has basically, five points of reference? I deviate from standard usage to call the points front and back; left, right and centre… assuming the dheight of the body is too slight to matter 

Left and right can't matter. Wingtip transponders gain what?

That leaves - untechnically - front, back and centre and takes us back to Tyzoid

Comment: The reason for "on top" is that most airplanes are flown with the top pointed more-or-less towards the sky, which is where the satellites are. If, on the other hand, one is flying their aircraft with the top pointed more-or-less towards the ground (such as while [keeping up foreign relations](https://youtu.be/wUZxSf_P2r0?t=45),) then having the GPS (and other satellite) antennas on the bottom would be better. Similarly, it's better for most antennas that communicate with ground stations to be placed on the bottom of the aircraft when not flying inverted.

Answer (score 8):

1. GPS signals need line of sight to the satellite, so positioning the antenna on top of the aircraft maximizes the satellites that can be seen and minimizes [multipathing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_propagation), and also gives some protection to ground based interference/jamming.
2. Not listed in the CAE but there are some advantages in not having critical cables running half the length of the aircraft, so the location may be the one that got a cheap, simple and easy to install and test location for the antenna, and per below it may not make a difference for this particular nav system.
3. Keeping the antenna near the C of G has two two effects, the first is that it means the position output is near the actual aircraft center, avoiding issues with systems having it off the side of the taxiway or showing altitude while still on the runway. There are also several effects the reduce the precision if there is rapid motion of the antenna during fixing, so a central location will get more accurate position. All of this can be 'solved' with software, but does make accurate GPS dependent on accurate pitch/roll information (and good software). Presumably in this case software was traded against the other effects of central location to produce the current placement.
4. Two antennas would be for redundancy. While aircraft can operate without GPS, it generally increases crew workload which produces risk of some other [problem causing a crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_flight_into_terrain).

Comment: To be more specific about point 3, while an aircraft is pitching, rolling, or yawing, it more or less rotates about the CofG.  So putting the antenna there keeps it moving with the path of the aircraft as a whole, not on a long level far from that. (The roll axis would be inside the fuselage, except at the nose/tail, so really it's pitch/yaw that you're fully avoiding by placing it at CofG.)

Answer (score 6):

1. All GPS signals are line of sight and most receivers use all
   satellites that are visible and a minimum of 9 - 12 degrees above
   the horizon. So being on the top of the aircraft near the centerline
   is essential to providing the best reception.
2. It's somewhat arbitrary as all antenna locations are a tradeoff. All
   the various antennae have to separated to avoid potential
   interference and parasitic effects. Cable lengths are an issue for
   two reasons. Signal attenuation and weight. Most of the antenna
   cables end up routed to the E/E bay aft of the nose gear well where
   the majority of the avionics are located (HF and radio altimeters
   are located in an aft bay.) I don't know why this diagram shows 4
   GPS antennae, 2 MMR and 2 'GPS'. I only know of the GPS receivers in
   the MMR. Every aircraft will have some variation is locations. The
   biggest known interferer for GPS is the VHF com, so keeping them
   separated is essential. Forward locations will avoid any shadowing
   by the vertical stabilizer/rudder.
3. The aircraft C.G. is the reference point for the navigation system.
   It's the point about which all aircraft rotation is measured. As the
   nature of the GPS solution is time difference of arrival of the
   signals from the satellites, the resolved position is that of the
   GPS antenna. The antenna location offset from the aircraft C.G. is
   loaded into each GPS(MMR) to allow the GPS to compensate for the
   offset. Additionally, the GPS data will be merged with the IRS data
   (which has its own compensation for installation location) in the
   FMS to obtain a hybrid GPS/IRS position. So ultimately any offset
   from the C.G. is accounted for. The only benefit of being close to
   the is to reduce 'noise' due to aircraft rotational motion
   (pitch/roll/yaw). Since it will always be present with even small
   offsets, there is an internal Kalman filter to reduce it to a
   minimum.
4. Navigation is an essential function whose loss is considered Major
   or Hazardous depending on phase of flight. In either case it
   requires redundancy so there are two of everything - GPS(MMR), FMS,
   etc. There may be 2 or 3 IRS depending on the system architecture
   and type of flight controls. Antennae can be shared between systems
   if they are simple antenna and meet a minimum reliability. Because
   GPS antennae are complex, containing an amplifier and downconverter,
   each GPS receiver has a dedicated antenna.

Answer (score 2):

Specific to question 2, that has not been addressed in other answers…  The GPS MMR antennae receive GPS augmentation signals.  In the case of WAAS, which is provided by stationary satellites, (SBAS), you want those on top.  But MMR augmentation also includes ground-based signals, (see GBAS), which are transmitted from the airport.  GBAS airports are rare today but are likely to become more common over time.  So the logical location that is line-of-sight to both satellites and the runway while on final approach is above the windshields.

Comment: The GBAS augmentation is broadcast using VHF Data Broadcast (VDB) on LOC/VOR frequencies, which the GPS antennae are incapable of receiving. Since the MMR has a perfectly functional VHF receiver (traditionally for LOC), it repurposes this hardware with supplemental software to receive the VDB signals via the LOC antenna when the GBAS landing function is selected.